How to pick a folder using Xamarin and Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree
I create the request and pick a folder on my sd card using this:
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);
this.StartActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FOLDER_REQUEST);

Then I get the resulting path using this:
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_FOLDER_REQUEST)
    {
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            string chosenPath = data.Data.toString();
            
            
        }
    }
}

The problem is that chosenPath contains:
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/3081-9B2D%3AMyFolder
When I need something like:
/storage/3081-9B2D/MyFolder
I could manually edit the string, but it could be an issue on other devices.
I've tried using ContentResolver.Query, but it says that the uri is invalid.
What is the correct way to get a user's picked folder using Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree in xamarin?

First of all, I suggest you still use the DocumentFile api instead of tring to get the real path when you use  Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree:
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_FOLDER_REQUEST)
    {
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
             DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.FromTreeUri(this,data.Data);
            if (documentFile.IsDirectory)
            {
               // do something
            }else{
               //do something
            }
        }
    }
}

You can use the DocumentFile.CreateFile() to create new files in the folder and read or write it. I will show the example about creating and writing:
if (documentFile.IsDirectory)
{
    var file = documentFile.CreateFile("text/*", "test.txt");
    var output = ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(file.Uri);
    var writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
    writer.Write("test to write");
    writer.Close();
}

If you still want to get the real path from the documentfile, you can refer to this thread: How to get the real path with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent.
